# when to close jersey SSE EventSource?

Tags: jersey-2.0

Jersey provides java API for SSE [EventSoruce](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.4.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/sse/EventSource.html).  But it's not clear when should client close it - when server close the connection, how does client get notified?  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

In case this question is still relevant :)

Close it when you shutdown the server, or want to close the connection.
Until you do, the connection will remain open - unless the client disconnects it, or some sort of IO exception happens.

In other words - the server takes care of everything, but you should know when you want to sever the connection.

(Y)